# why the double matrix results is different from the integer matrix results in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, matrix, double

I have two codes to do exactly the same thing, the only difference is that in the first code I am using an integer array where in the second code, I am using a double array. The first code is running perfectly, but the second one have a lot of mistakes.
Both codes, suppose to loop through the first matrix "pathPoints", take all the paths from the small arrays inside and get their weights from the "F" matrix then add all these weights together and output it, I attaches both codes:

```
public class PathFlowCalculator {

    static final int N = 6;

    private final int[][][] pathPoints = {
            { { 0 }, { 0, 1 }, { 0, 3, 2 }, { 0, 3 }, { 0, 3, 2, 4 }, {0, 5 } },
            { { 1, 2, 4, 0 }, { 1 }, { 1, 2 }, { 1, 2, 3 }, { 1, 2, 4 }, { 1, 5  } },
            { { 2, 4, 0 }, { 2, 4, 1 }, { 2 }, { 2, 3 }, { 2, 4 }, { 2, 5 } },
            { { 3, 0 }, { 3, 1 }, { 3, 2 }, { 3 }, { 3, 2, 4}, { 3, 1, 5 } },
            { { 4, 0 }, { 4, 1 }, { 4, 2 }, { 4, 3 }, { 4 }, { 4, 1, 5 } },
            { {  5, 2, 4, 0 }, { 5, 1 }, { 5, 2 }, { 5, 3 }, { 5, 2, 4 }, { 5 } }
    };
    private final int[][] F = {
            {0, 9, 11, 12, 8, 12},
            {18, 0, 15, 10, 17, 18},
            {17, 18, 0, 14, 10, 10},
            {17, 8, 10, 0, 17, 18},
            {15, 9, 12, 14, 0, 16},
            {18, 16, 15, 8, 9, 0}
    };

    // this is where we store results
    private final int[][] flowPerStep = new int[N][N];

    public PathFlowCalculator() {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                int[] currentPath = pathPoints[i][j];
                int currentFlow = F[i][j];
                for (int k = 0; k < currentPath.length - 1; k++) {
                    int fromNode = currentPath[k];
                    int toNode = currentPath[k + 1];
                    flowPerStep[fromNode][toNode] += currentFlow;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //This is the main method

    public static void main(String... argv) {

        //Declaring couple of arrays to be used inside this function to store the results in
        //So that I can pass the results later
        long startTime  = System.currentTimeMillis();

        PathFlowCalculator calc = new PathFlowCalculator();
        for (int o=0; o<N; o++){
            for(int p=0;p<N;p++){
                System.out.print(calc.flowPerStep[o][p]+ "     ");
            }
            System.out.println();

            //The same function I used in FloydWarshall.java to compute the CPU usage and load

        }

    }

}
```

The output for this is below which is perfect:

```
0     9     0     31     0     12     
0     0     60     0     0     52     
0     0     0     24     132     10     
17     26     46     0     0     0     
68     43     12     14     0     0     
0     16     42     8     0     0
```

Here is the second code, except the F matrix now in double and I want the output to be in double as well, I just changed the fields' names

```
public class Actual {

    static final int N = 6;
    final static int INF = 999999999;


    private final int[][][] path = {
            { { 0 }, { 0, 1 }, { 0, 3, 2 }, { 0, 3 }, { 0, 3, 2, 4 }, {0, 5 } },
            { { 1, 2, 4, 0 }, { 1 }, { 1, 2 }, { 1, 2, 3 }, { 1, 2, 4 }, { 1, 5  } },
            { { 2, 4, 0 }, { 2, 4, 1 }, { 2 }, { 2, 3 }, { 2, 4 }, { 2, 5 } },
            { { 3, 0 }, { 3, 1 }, { 3, 2 }, { 3 }, { 3, 2, 4}, { 3, 1, 5 } },
            { { 4, 0 }, { 4, 1 }, { 4, 2 }, { 4, 3 }, { 4 }, { 4, 1, 5 } },
            { {  5, 2, 4, 0 }, { 5, 1 }, { 5, 2 }, { 5, 3 }, { 5, 2, 4 }, { 5 } }
    };
    private final double[][] FF = {
            {0.0, 19.6, INF, 79.33, INF, 21.0},
            {INF, 0.0, 42.5, INF, 10, 42},
            {9.0, 10.0, 0.0, 29.33, 180.0, 13.5},
            {30.86, 15.56, 11.2, 0.0, INF, INF},
            {207.0, 48.0, 23.33, 150.0, 0.0, INF},
            {INF, 85.0, 120.0, 18.89, INF, 0.0}
    };

    // this is where we store results
    private final double[][] result = new double[N][N];

    public Actual() {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                int[] current = path[i][j];
                double currentFlow = FF[i][j];
                for (int r = 0; r < current.length - 1; r++) {
                    int from = current[r];
                    int to = current[r + 1];
                    result[from][to] += currentFlow;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {

        Actual calcc = new Actual();
        for (int w=0; w<N; w++){
            for(int e=0;e<N;e++){
                System.out.print(calcc.result[w][e]+ "     ");
            }
            System.out.println();

        }

    }

}
```

But I am having a wrong output which is below:

```
0.0     19.6     0.0     2.00000007733E9     0.0     21.0     
0.0     0.0     2.0000000505E9     0.0     0.0     2.00000004E9     
0.0     0.0     0.0     1.00000002833E9     5.000000204E9     13.5     
30.86     1.00000001456E9     3.0000000082E9     0.0     0.0     0.0     
2.000000214E9     1.000000057E9     23.33     150.0     0.0     0.0     
0.0     85.0     2.000000118E9     18.89     0.0     0.0
```

Would someone explain why is that happening please, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of overflow. Consider the following two examples:

```
    double x = 79.33+999999;
    System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(x)));
    System.out.println(x);

  Result:   
    100000100101110100001010001110010101000111101011100001010001111
    1000078.33
```

The above works just fine.

Now, if I add 9999999

```
    double x = 79.33+9999999;
    System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(x)));
    System.out.println(x);

Result:
    100000101100011000100101101100111001010100011110101110000101001
    1.000007833E7
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot @codepi but even if I change the INF to 0 I will still have some wrong answers and in some cases the answer should be only 90 but I am still getting long numbers instead